# django can't load the model's information to template

Tags: python, mysql, database, django, web-applications

I'm using Django with MySQL. I have a Post model. If I execute `Post.object.all()` in python shell, it shows all the Post objects.

However, when I add

```
posts = Post.objects.all()

return render(request, 'index.html', {'posts': posts})
```

in `views.py`

and

```
{% for post in posts %}
 {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

in `index.html`

I simply can't see the post names on my index page. What's wrong with my codes ?  How can I know if I have passed posts to the template successfully?

Comment: The code looks correct. Are you sure that you are viewing the page associated with this view?

Comment: The code looks alright, you can pass an static value to the template and verify if it's displayed correctly, otherwise it's an error with something else.

Comment: To know if you passed the object successfully try this one `{{posts}}` and make sure you're in the right page. Check urls.py